# Different Projects for different Databases?

Tags: c#, database, architecture

I have two databases, one for user information, and one that contains data from/for the main portion of my website. From what I've seen, it is good practice to have a class library project that contains database access stuff that is separate from the MVC main project. Should I create a separate class library for each database or put the information for both of them in the same class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not forced to make a separate project for each Databases but you can. On the other hand you sould separate namespaces for each models. Be carefull when you say "database access stuff", don't store connections strings on that kind of project. The only project that should choose witch Database to target is your "Main" project (MVC in this case). The libs you wanted to create sould only be a representation of database structure (+ repository pattern if you don't have ORM)

All architecture questions are relatives and can be answered differents ways that work in each cases. **Find the best you feel confortable with.**

Comment: Where should I store connection strings? In the Main project?

Comment: Of course you should, but just the connections strings.

Comment: As a IOC container must be congured in the last project ("Main project") of your application. This way, you have one unique configuration point per "Main project". Are you using IOC injection framework ?

Comment: I don't even know what IOC stands for, so I'm not sure. I'm using EF Core and MySql

Comment: An IOC container is used to register, resolve and dispose instances. But it is going far from the initial question. You will find some informations about IOC on googling this ;)

Comment: @Bubinga Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?

Comment: I did yes, I went to bed and did stuff today so that's why I'm late to mark it as a "correct answer"